# How do you get around generic functions not respecting associated types as derivable?

Tags: swift, generics, inheritance, protocols

*[Here is the actual code](https://github.com/Catterwaul/HemiprocneMystacea/blob/develop/HemiprocneMystacea/UIKit/dequeuedReusableCell.swift), that I want to improve.*

In `cell`, I want to enforce that `Cell` is a subclass of `Self.Cell`, which we know will derive from `UIView`, meaning that it itself is a class.

```
import UIKit

// Conforming types will have a function called `cell`
// which returns a subclass of `Cell`
protocol cell {
   typealias Cell: UIView
}

extension UICollectionView: cell {
   typealias Cell = UICollectionViewCell
}
extension UITableView: cell {
   typealias Cell = UITableViewCell
}

extension cell {
   // Error, because Self.Cell is not a protocol
   func cell<Cell: Self.Cell>() -> Cell! {
      // The real function shouldn't return 
      // an implicitly unwrapped optional
      // but getting this to compile will solve my problem.
      return nil
   }
}
```

Comment: Why  not simply `func doSomething(with cell: Cell) {}` ?

Comment: That doesn't enforce that Cell derives from Self.Cell, only UIView, which is not specific enough. And more importantly, there's no way to return Cell.

Comment: Are you sure, did you try it?

Comment: I don't know what trying would be; what you're asking sounds like an untryable thing as far as I can figure. I edited the code to be closer to the real problem.

Comment: why is the function generic to begin with? `func cell() -> Cell! ` / `cell(someCell: Cell) -> Cell` works just fine for me. `typealias` in a `protocol` is already very similar to a generic param.

Comment: See "a function called `cell` which returns a subclass of `Cell`". Self.Cell is not specific enough.

Comment: What does "Self.Cell is not specific enough" mean?

Comment: `Self.Cell` is either a `UICollectionViewCell` or a `UITableViewCell`, which is the direct superclass of whatever I actually want the function to return.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to ensure that the returned cell is a subclass of the type provided by the conforming type, it makes more sense to add this to the protocol requirement instead of trying to return a view for each `Cell` type with a single method in an extension of the protocol

```
// Written in Swift 5.2
protocol cell {
    associatedtype Cell: UIView
    func cell() -> Cell!
}

extension UICollectionView: cell {
    typealias Cell = UICollectionViewCell

    func cell() -> UICollectionViewCell! {
        UICollectionViewCell()
    }
}
extension UITableView: cell {
    typealias Cell = UITableViewCell

    func cell() -> UITableViewCell! {
        UITableViewCell()
    }
}
```

The conforming types are free to return whatever subclass they want, and the `cell()` method will return a `UIView` that inherits from the cell class specified by the type. Note, however, that extending these classes prevents subclasses from overriding the protocol's methods and specifying cells of their own.

This is an old thread and you are probably already aware of this now. Hopefully this helped regardless.